# Как сделать отключение элементов?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать отключение элементов в скрипте. Есть такой скрипт при нажатии на два блока появляется третий блок. А как сделать так что бы при включении трех элементов два выключалось и оставался один третий элемент который включился. Код можно посмотреть тут https://codepen.io/avdoshka/pen/ExgvEgP

```
document.addEventListener('click', function _tmp(e) {
let block = e.target.closest('.block');
if (!block) return; // return прервет функцию, если кликнули не на нужный блок.

block.classList.toggle('clicked');

if (document.querySelectorAll('.block.clicked').length == 2) {
// .block.clicked без пробела: Все элементы, у которых есть оба класса
document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = "block";
// После завершения, обработчик клика удаляется.

var line = document.querySelector('.block3' );

} else document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = "none";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
var line = document.querySelector('.block3');
line.disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

При включении всех четырех блоков должен появиться пятый блог и исчезнуть четыре остальные.  Код тут codepen.io/avdoshka/pen/ExgvEgP